# obtain UK visa from Egypt and travel from another country

Tags: visas, uk

I am going to apply for visa to do ID check for GMC registration

I would like to ask is it possible to obtain the visa from Egypt and travel using it from Czech Republic on January as I will be there for a medical fellowship or I have to apply for the visa from Czech republic

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that. Applying for your UK visa in Egypt does not require that you arrive in the UK directly from Egypt. As long as your visa is valid when you arrive, you won't face any problems arriving in the UK from the Czech Republic.